# How do Trainers work in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been to one or two trainers for Destruction magic already.  Since then, if I go to another trainer (different skill) of a level that I've already trained at, the dialog says I've maxed out my training (5/5).

So, it seems to me that you can only train five times at a given training level (Common, Expert, Master) *across all skills*.  However, given how many different skills there are in the game and how many Trainers there are, this seems rather crippling to me.

Can someone explain exactly how Training works?  Is my above presumption correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only train 5 skill levels per (character) level.

So if you are level 10 and train destruction at a trainer you can train 5 times. Then you have to get to level 11 to be able to buy skill levels at a trainer.

That is the only restriction I know of (being lvl 62 atm).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you guessed right - but honestly, it is not a big matter. You should only use trainers for skills that you want to learn but don't want to USE routinely (for example you don't want to keep doing alchemy things all the time but want to abillity for better potions: use an alchemy trainer).

Because in skyrim you gain skill points by using the skill you level up your skills pretty fast just by using them constantly. So, if you wear heavy armor, use a one handed sword and shield, all those skills will grow rapidly without you needing a trainer.

Comment: Could you expend a bit more on this?  I've edited my question to be a bit more clear.  My guess was that you can only train five times per *training* level, but I'm reading other wikis now that seem to indicate it's five times (non-cumulative) per *character* level.  If that's the case, my level 45 character has missed out on a *lot* of training!

Comment: You can train five times per character level. At level 1 you can train five times; at level 2 you can train five times; and so on. It is not related to the level of your skill. You can train one skill five times, or five skills once, or any other combination.

Comment: This answer is not correct, but the comment from @victoriah is

Comment: @Iszi Don't worry, your character didn't really lose anything by not using the services of trainers constantly. Skill levels gained through training behave exactly like skill levels gained through regular gameplay. Every 10 skill levelups you get a character levelup, no matter if you gained those 10 levelups through training or playing. In fact, training through playing is usually better for the character, because whatever activities you performed to level your character likely made it richer instead of poorer.

Comment: Actually, character XP earned per skill up is variable. In Helgen, raising a few skills a few levels will level you up once or twice. Grinding a few skills to 100 in Helgen like 1H or 2H can see you leaving there at level 35. Grinding 1H and Block to high but not max levels and sneak to 100 17 times can see you leaving at level 81. If you grind for levels using Telekinesis fast traveling at fairly high levels(say between 135 and 175) a single skill mastering fro 15 to 100 may only raise your character by a level or two.

Answer (score 0):

Trainers are found all around Skyrim. They train you each skill. There are 3 types of trainers: Common, Expert, and Master. You can only train 5 times per level. Here are what the trainers can train you to:

Common: 0-50

Expert: 0-75

Master: 0-90

Now it's possible to level above the maximum by  being one level below, and not trainer 5 times yet. Go trainer 5 times and it should be above maximum.

Example:

Trainer: Master 0-90

Player: 89

When the player trains five times he\she should get level 94.